# Multiple File Type Parser

Tags: java, parsing

this is my first post here. I'm excited to finally take part.

I'm working on a project where I'm parsing obscure files types. I need to be able to parse word (which I've already done), .sbs, .day, .cmp, and more. All of these types can be opened simply with notepad and displayed.

Since I'm so new to this stuff, is there a way I can use some generic library (or two) to open all of these up? And if so what library would it be?

What's a best practice in this sort of circumstance?

Thanks!

Comment: What language do you have in mind for this project?

Comment: Sorry, I may have missed this: I'm programming in Java.

Comment: @jQwierdy Do you just want to do is open a file and save to a text variable?

Comment: A text variable is fine, as we will be then iterating through the parsed data at different points and then writing to an output file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) library. [`FileUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) class has several methods that receives the file path and optionlly the file encoding.

If you just want to only read text files and save them to a text variable

```
java.io.File file = new java.io.File("C:\\dir\\file.cmp");
String allWordAndLines = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
```

If you want each line separately and store them in a collection:

```
java.util.List<String> lines = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readLines(file);
for(String line : lines) {
    // do something with line
}
```

To specify the encoding, you need to add another parameter:

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8");
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readLines(file, "Cp1252");
```

Java include several classes for read files, see more in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html

I hope this can help you if you are looking for only to have your text file is available in memory.

Comment: It is unclear to me whether the OP just wants to read the file in as text or parse it according to their proper internal format -- parsing word files suggests to me the latter.

Comment: I would like the latter, however I don't believe its possible. These formats are very software specific I believe so we might have to do our own analysis of them. But if anyone can tell me if they know of possible parsers let me know.